# Running post build actions with external jobs in Jenkins

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit, clover

I'd like to run phpunit on an external server, the feed those results into a Jenkins plugin like the Clover PHP Coverage Report action.

The code base has some library dependancies that the owner of the Jenkins server does not want deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Well with some tweaking I guess it is possible to make use of the [monitoring external plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs). You will have to figure something out to get the files on the jenkins server.

An other option is, if the server owner is willing, to create a specific build agent for your needs. That doesn't affect his jobs and you can use your builds like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, library dependencies shouldn't be installed globally on a Jenkins server, but this is where Composer comes into play: You'd essentially install exactly the dependencies your current software needs locally in the workspace of your job.

Nobody should be bothered by this, because you could also include the needed library code there manually - or even worse, you could use the same file and class names and code something entirely different. All of this must not interfere with any other job running on that same server, and it doesn't.

You can't really avoid Composer, because PHPUnit will stop being distributed via PEAR, as well as some Symfony components that are being used. Better go to the [Composer project](https://getcomposer.org/) page and learn how to use it. By the way: You can include the needed version of PHPUnit with Composer as well, so you need not rely on a centrally installed version (which is hard to update because there are so many jobs that would need updates then - too much work in one go).

Comment: I should have been more clear.. I am using composer, but it's loading an custom package that depends on having standalone log4php in its own source tree.  It's just one of those things I have to work around.  To make it even more lame, the base app is using its own version of log4php with composer.

Comment: Well, then you better change that instead of installing that dependency. There really is no reason to force code to be inside special paths.